# rate not showing in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, fetch-api

I am trying to echo out the rate  but it's not showing. What is the actual reason. Can anyone help mw with it?

Here's the code

```
<?php

// Create the shortcode
function currency_conversion_shortcode() {
    $url = "https://api.fastforex.io/convert?from=AED&to=NPR&amount=1&api_key=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx";// api key added on purpose

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    return $result['result'] . " NPR";
}
add_shortcode( 'currency_conversion', 'currency_conversion_shortcode' );

?>
```

Response data

{
"base": "AED",
"amount": 1,
"result": {
"NPR": 35.56,
"rate": 35.5597
},
"ms": 5
}

Comment: The return value of a shortcode function should be a string value. The `result` property of your decoded JSON is not that, it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function currency_conversion_shortcode()
{
    $url = "https://api.fastforex.io/convert?from=AED&to=NPR&amount=1&api_key=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx";

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    return $result['result']['rate'] . " NPR";
}

add_shortcode('currency_conversion', 'currency_conversion_shortcode');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).